# visual svn http syntax

Tags: visual-studio, svn, visualsvn-server, visualsvn

For the purpose of integration with ALM Octane I need to come up with VisualSVN http syntax to show diff of files. The version of VisualSVN I use is 3.6.0

• File link template. A template for the HTTP link to the file view of a selected file.

• Diff link template. A template for the HTTP link to the diff view of a selected file version.

The syntax examples for BitBucket I have are those:

```
File link template: myServer:myPort/myRepository/browse/{filePath}?until={revision}&at={revision}
Diff link template: myServer:myPort/myRepository/diff/{filePath}?until={revision}&at={revision}
```

I have no syntax examples for VisualSVN.

The File link template came up at something like that:
protocol:address:port/svn/repository/{filePath}?p={revision}
Trivial: https://myserver:8443/svn/myrepository/thatfolder/{filePath}?p={revision}
This works with VisualSVN.

However Diff link template is something I can't find info on how to do. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The web-based repository browser in VisualSVN Server 3.6 currently accepts the following URL patterns for web links.

- Item view ([example #1](https://demo-server.visualsvn.com/!/#wordpress/view/head/trunk/src/wp-login.php), [example #2](https://demo-server.visualsvn.com/!/#wordpress/view/r1000/trunk)):

  `https://<hostname>/!/#$<repository>/view/r${rev}/{path}`
- Changeset view ([example](https://demo-server.visualsvn.com/!/#wordpress/commit/r40395)):

  `https://<hostname>/!/#$<repository>/commit/r${rev}/`

Please note that we are going to improve the web interface in future server updates. Drop us a line at support@visualsvn.com if you would like to share any feedback or suggestions.